# How to set method name prefix in swagger codegen?

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

(Newbie to Swagger)

In the swagger specification file, the operationId is the name of the operation, corresponding to the HTTP methods.

For example,

```
 "/pet/findByStatus": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Finds Pets by status",
        "description": "Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings",
        "operationId": "findPetsByStatus",
```

As seen above, operationId = findPetsByStatus. Suppose I want to generate a prefix for all get operations in my java code, with prefix = 'get_'.

For example, I would expect the swagger codegen to produce all operations corresponding to HTTP GET methods with a prefix = 'get_'. Specifically, above, it might generate: get_findPetsByStatus.

Is there a way to tell swagger codegen to prefix methods?

Please note that I want to use swagger-codegen itself and not APIMatic-like alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [AbstractJavaCodegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java) (or a subclass that implements it) and overload the postProcessOperations function to prepend prefixes to operations (operationId property of the CodegenOperation class). See [making-your-own-codegen-modules](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules) for instructions on building and running a custom codegen.

Pseudocode:

```
public class MyCodegen extends AbstractJavaCodegen{ \\or 
    [...]
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> postProcessOperations(Map<String, Object> objs) {
        super.postProcessOperations(objs);
        Map<String, Object> operations = (Map<String, Object>) objs.get("operations");
        if (operations != null) {
            List<CodegenOperation> ops = (List<CodegenOperation>) operations.get("operation");
            for (CodegenOperation operation : ops) {
                if(operation.httpMethod.equals("GET"){
                    operation.operationId = "get_" + operation.operationId;
                }[...]
            }
        }
        return objs;
    }
}
```